# Inequality on inner product which does not involve the norms

Tags: matrices, inequality, vector-spaces, inner-products, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Most of the inequalities I know, concerning inner products induced by positive a definite matrix $P\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ (the identity as a simple example) on $\mathbb{R}^n$, involve majorizing with the norms of the entries.

My question is, given a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ (nonlinear), is there some relevant inequality of the form
$$ \langle x,f(Wx+y)-f(y) \rangle_P\leq L\langle x,Wx\rangle_P$$
where $W\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and $L\in\mathbb{R}$ possibly depends on $P$, $x$ and anything needed?

My guess is that there can be something involving the Logarithmic norm of either $P$ or $W$. Of course I do not need necessarily a result holding for any $f$, it could be really helpful even some particular case or some property which, when satisfied by $f$, gives out this kind of inequality.

An interesting case might even be when $f$ is made by the same function acting componentwise. Indeed, if there is a $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ so that $f(x) = (g(x_1),...,g(x_n))$.

Comment: I don't think this is always possible. E.g. when $P=I_2,\ W$ is the $2\times2$ rotation matrix for the angle $\pi/2$ and $x=(1,1)^T$, we have $\langle x,Wx\rangle_P=0$. Now, if $y=0,\ f(0)=0$ and $f(Wx)=x$, the LHS of the inequality is positive but the RHS is zero.

Comment: Yes sure, so the question is if introducing nonlinearity (as mentioned in the question), there are situations in which the desired inequality might be true

Comment: I was talking about a specific $W$ and a specific $x\,(=(1,1)^T)$ in my previous comment. There are lots of nonlinear $f$s such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(Wx)=x$, such as the entrywise square of a vector.